# Should I specify the maximum size of the memory allocation pool for my java app running on t2.nano?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, procfile

Is it good practice to specify `-Xmx` variable in a `Procfile` when running Java application on t2.nano with Elastic Beanstalk? This should leave some memory for the operating system to work properly.